# How to set 2nd row as header? (Azure Data Factory)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Excel file with a title, headers and then data. In ADF I delete the the title from the dataset, but ADF automatically adds 'Column_1','Column_2' as headers. I want it to use the new first row as header.
Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried using the first row as header configuration, however this doesn't work as the new header news are 'Column_1',etc.

[image]

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my experience, delete the first title and then set first row as header can work. You can try to clear your schema and import it again. You can also use Range in dataset to do this.

[image]

Comment: The first two solutions I already tried, but with no success. We will have multiple files coming in the lake for consumption with the same format. Is there a possibility to make this dynamic? So only read from row 2 for example

Comment: As far as I know, It's impossible. Have you tried to only type `A2` in Range setting?

Comment: @TimHellegers I'm glad to hear that. If you think my answer help you, you can mark it as answer. Thanks a lot.